# how to implement Auto-Renewing Subscription for In-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing movie app and want to have Auto-Renewing Subscription

I want to know, i can do that Auto-Renewing Subscription in my app?

or Auto-Renewing can do Newsstand app.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the subscription is auto-renewing or not is handled not in the app, but rather in iTunes connect when you create your product: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW1

Whether the subscription auto-renews or not, the handling is described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6